# Is there a way to remove objects from a Tiled map?

Tags: libgdx, tiled, tmxtiledmap

I am looping through object layer and there are certain objects(Rectangle Map object in my case) I want to remove based on certain condition, but I don't see any method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

there are two methods for your use case:

- `com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObjects#remove(com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject)`
- `com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObjects#remove(int)`

See https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapObjects.html

So I guess you will do something like this:

```java
            ArrayList<MapObject> objectsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

            for (MapObject object : mapLayer.getObjects()) {
                if (object.getName().contains("removeMe")) // TODO
                {
                    objectsToRemove.add(object);
                }
            }
            for (MapObject mapObject : objectsToRemove) {
                mapLayer.getObjects().remove(mapObject);
            }
```